# python how to match dic value with list items

Tags: python, dictionary

```
countr={'517132': 2017, '1002063365': 116, '226022': 34, '51002': 3, '219006': 117, '222034': 45, '224032': 42, '517195': 103, '731120': 1516
'3254':12,'456':11}

r1=[224032, 517132, 226022, 1002063365, 222034, 219006, 517195, 35015, 731120, 51002]
r={}
for i in r1:
r[i]=countr.get(i)
```

i was trying to make new dic 
what i mean was if countr key is matched with r1 value

add in new dic r value as key and countr matched value as value.
but when i learn this code result is None.

```
'224032':None, '517132'=None....'1002063365':None]
```

is there any way to match dic value with list?
and this is my desired output

```
r=[517132': 2017, '1002063365': 116, '226022': 34, '51002': 3, '219006': 117, '222034': 45, '224032': 42, '517195': 103, '731120': 1516]
```

Comment: Your `dict` keys are strings... that is why this is failing.

Comment: can you suggest me what to do?

Comment: You should figure out if you want to use strings or ints, and then use the appropriate one...

Comment: Also, your example output is not a valid Python literal... and seems to imply you want *strings* as keys in the final `dict` as well.

Comment: i want to use string can you show me example ?

Comment: `r = {str(e):countr.get(str(e)) for e in r1}`

Comment: thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get it right this is what you want:

```
countr={'517132': 2017, '1002063365': 116, '226022': 34, '51002': 3, '219006': 117, '222034': 45 ,'224032': 42, '517195': 103, '731120': 1516,
'3254':12,'456':11}

r1=[224032, 517132, 226022, 1002063365, 222034, 219006, 517195, 35015, 731120, 51002]
r={}
for key in countr:
  if key in str(r1):
    r[key]=countr[key]

print(r)
```

output:
`{'517132': 2017, '1002063365': 116, '226022': 34, '51002': 3, '219006': 117, '222034': 45, '224032': 42, '517195': 103, '731120': 1516}`

You may also need to reconsider if r1 is int or sting to much dictionary values

Comment: It probably makes more sense to iterate over `r1` instead of the dictionary, and instead of the wasteful list-membership test, you should use `countr.get`

Comment: `if key in str(r1)` will fail if a `countr` key is a substring of a r1 element.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the list elements:

```
countr = {'517132': 2017, '1002063365': 116, '226022': 34, '51002': 3, '219006': 117,
          '222034': 45, '224032': 42, '517195': 103, '731120': 1516, '3254': 12, '456': 11}

r1 = [224032, 517132, 226022, 1002063365,
      222034, 219006, 517195, 35015, 731120, 51002]

print({k: countr[str(k)] for k in r1 if str(k) in countr})
# {224032: 42, 517132: 2017, 226022: 34, 1002063365: 116, 222034: 45, 219006: 117, 517195: 103, 731120: 1516, 51002: 3}
print({k: countr.get(str(k)) for k in r1})
# {224032: 42, 517132: 2017, 226022: 34, 1002063365: 116, 222034: 45, 219006: 117, 517195: 103, 35015: None, 731120: 1516, 51002: 3}
```

It's faster and more robust this way. The accepted answer would fail with this example:

```
countr={'1': 2017, '2': 116}
r1=[12]
```